# Debugging singleton in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, singleton

I can see the properties of a singleton in its own class (file), but I can't see them in other files in the debugger. Since singleton acts as a global variable, why I can't or how to see it on the debugger? Do I have to assign the singleton to another local variable so that I can watch the local variable instead of the singleton?

Comment: A singleton isn't a global variable, it's a global method.  To see it, in the console type `po [SingletonClass singleInstance]`.

Comment: @HotLicks Then how can I see the property inside the singletonInstance. For example, if I want to see all the objects in an array, do I have to type po [blah blah blah] individually to see all the objects?

Comment: If you do `po` on an array it will display all the objects, exactly like NSLog.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you have a `sharedInstance` class method

```
@implementation MySingleton

+ (MySingleton *)sharedInstance {
    static MySingleton *_sharedInstance = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t once_token = 0;
    dispatch_once(&once_token, ^{
        _sharedInstance = [[MySingleton alloc] init];
    });

    return _sharedInstance;
}

@end
```

and access it via

```
MySingleton *mySingleton = [MySingleton sharedInstance];
```